# Bad Request - Invalid URL using a call towards an endpoint

Tags: wso2, wso2-micro-integrator, wso2-esb

I have been trying to understand why this is happening. My ESB does a call towards https://login.microsoftonline.com/ in order to obtain a token which I use to do a call towards an endpoint. The problem is that when a call is sent with my ESB I get:

```html
[2021-11-01 14:42:17,226] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-01 14:42:17,226] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-01 14:42:17,227] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Date: Mon, 01 Nov 2021 12:42:16 GMT[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-01 14:42:17,228] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Connection: close[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-01 14:42:17,228] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Content-Length: 324[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-01 14:42:17,229] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-01 14:42:17,230] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-01 14:42:17,231] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-01 14:42:17,231] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-01 14:42:17,232] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid URL</h2>[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-01 14:42:17,233] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.</p>[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-01 14:42:17,234] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "</BODY></HTML>[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-01 14:42:17,259] ERROR {RelayUtils} - Error while building Passthrough stream org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '"' (code 34) in DOCTYPE declaration; expected a space between public and system identifiers
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,50]
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:165)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:169)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:122)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.buildMessage(AbstractListMediator.java:152)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:95)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:260)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:809)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:309)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:583)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:197)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:285)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '"' (code 34) in DOCTYPE declaration; expected a space between public and system identifiers
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,50]
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedChar(StreamScanner.java:639)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.startDTD(BasicStreamReader.java:2487)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromPrologBang(BasicStreamReader.java:2403)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2063)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1134)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
        ... 19 more

[2021-11-01 14:42:17,261] ERROR {SequenceMediator} - {api:smp-serviceability-check-api} Error while building message. Error while building Passthrough stream org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while building Passthrough stream
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.handleException(RelayUtils.java:452)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:215)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:122)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.buildMessage(AbstractListMediator.java:152)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:95)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:260)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:809)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:309)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:583)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:197)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:285)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '"' (code 34) in DOCTYPE declaration; expected a space between public and system identifiers
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,50]
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:165)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:169)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '"' (code 34) in DOCTYPE declaration; expected a space between public and system identifiers
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,50]
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedChar(StreamScanner.java:639)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.startDTD(BasicStreamReader.java:2487)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromPrologBang(BasicStreamReader.java:2403)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2063)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1134)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
        ... 19 more

[2021-11-01 14:42:17,277]  INFO {LogMediator} - {api:smp-serviceability-check-api} To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:dcbc17c0-5dc7-46d5-b7f6-db5f3e571506, Direction: request, MESSAGE = An unexpected error occured, message = Error while building message. Error while building Passthrough stream, message = 601000, message = org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Error while building message. Error while building Passthrough stream
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractMediator.handleException(AbstractMediator.java:376)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.buildMessage(AbstractListMediator.java:154)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:95)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:260)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:809)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:309)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:583)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:197)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:285)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while building Passthrough stream
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.handleException(RelayUtils.java:452)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:215)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:122)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.buildMessage(AbstractListMediator.java:152)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '"' (code 34) in DOCTYPE declaration; expected a space between public and system identifiers
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,50]
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:165)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:169)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '"' (code 34) in DOCTYPE declaration; expected a space between public and system identifiers
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,50]
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedChar(StreamScanner.java:639)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.startDTD(BasicStreamReader.java:2487)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromPrologBang(BasicStreamReader.java:2403)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2063)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1134)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
        ... 19 more
, message = org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Error while building message. Error while building Passthrough stream, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope>
```

I went through a lot of scenarios where there were unwanted Cookies, Header Parameters, bad Content Type and etc. which I removed using fields bellow:

```
<!-- Chaning ContentType to none-->
<property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="none"/>
<!-- Removing custom Header Params -->
<property action="remove" name="x-ms-ests-server" scope="transport"/>
<property action="remove" name="x-ms-request-id" scope="transport"/>
<!-- Removing all the header params and cookies -->
<property action="remove" name="EXCESS_TRANSPORT_HEADERS" scope="axis2"/>
<property action="remove" name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" scope="axis2"/>
<property action="remove" name="Set-Cookie" scope="transport"/>
<!-- Removing /query parameter received by the API -->
<property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value=""/>
```

At the end I just created a simple call request that goes directly to the endpoint with Hardcoded URL, Bearer token and everything. ( It doesn't get the token, it skips that part so that the whole thing is just one call towards an endpoint ).

```
    <property name="Authorization" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="Bearer TOKEN_IS_HERE"/>
<property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value=""/>
<property action="remove" name="ContentType" scope="axis2"/>
<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="none"/>
<property name="HTTP_METHOD" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="GET"/>
<call>
    <endpoint>
        <address statistics="enable" trace="enable" uri="https://sub-domain.dns.net?qparam=999999999">
            <suspendOnFailure>
                <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                <progressionFactor>1</progressionFactor>
            </suspendOnFailure>
            <markForSuspension>
                <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
            </markForSuspension>
        </address>
    </endpoint>
</call>
```

And I still keep getting Bad Request - Invalid URL. Using **postman the direct call works without a problem** and I copy all the parameters from the MI log.. I have also tested each Parameter that was sent before simplifying the code, by manually adding them in the postman request to see if it will break but none of them did. I tried different messageTypes and ContentTypes but same thing.

Here is how my get call looks like in the wire logs

```
[2021-11-01 14:57:40,243]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} - Sending message through endpoint : null resolving to address = https://sub-domain.dns.net?qparam=999999999
[2021-11-01 14:57:40,243]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} - SOAPAction: null
[2021-11-01 14:57:40,245]  INFO {TRACE_LOGGER} - WSA-Action: null
[2021-11-01 14:57:40,254]  INFO {TimeoutHandler} - This engine will expire all callbacks after GLOBAL_TIMEOUT: 120 seconds, irrespective of the timeout action, after the specified or optional timeout
[2021-11-01 14:57:41,045] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "GET ?qparam=999999999 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-01 14:57:41,046] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Authorization: Bearer THE_TOKEN[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-01 14:57:41,047] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Accept: */*[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-01 14:57:41,047] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Postman-Token: 69862f3a-1404-4f4b-b6a7-cc67d1197b5c[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-01 14:57:41,048] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-01 14:57:41,049] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Content-Type: none[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-01 14:57:41,049] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Host: sub-domain.dns.net[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-01 14:57:41,049] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-01 14:57:41,050] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "User-Agent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-01 14:57:41,050] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "[\r][\n]"
```

Other things I tried are changing the call endpoint to

```
    <endpoint>
       <http method="get" uri-template="https://sub-domain.dns.net?qparam=999999999"/>
    </endpoint>
```

but didn't work. Any ideas are really apricated why this is happening.

Edit: Tested with Free APIs in http and https and they work..

HTTP:

```
[2021-11-02 11:13:11,121] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "GET /users?_limit=2 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:13:11,122] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Accept: */*[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:13:11,123] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Postman-Token: 945d1aa2-9553-42dd-a471-e9dd106f09df[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:13:11,125] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:13:11,126] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "eti-organizationid: org634bbfb6[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:13:11,126] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Content-Type: none[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:13:11,127] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Host: fakeapi.jsonparseronline.com[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:13:11,128] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:13:11,129] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "User-Agent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:13:11,129] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:13:11,254] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:13:11,255] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Server: Cowboy[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:13:11,256] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:13:11,256] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "X-Powered-By: Express[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:13:11,257] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Vary: Origin, Accept-Encoding[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:13:11,257] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:13:11,257] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Cache-Control: no-cache[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:13:11,258] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Pragma: no-cache[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:13:11,258] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Expires: -1[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:13:11,258] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "X-Total-Count: 50[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:13:11,259] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Total-Count[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:13:11,259] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:13:11,259] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:13:11,260] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Etag: W/"4c9-6aU1Y/ePEQDvH83MhgvZYvJUcUg"[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:13:11,261] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Content-Encoding: gzip[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:13:11,261] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Date: Tue, 02 Nov 2021 09:13:11 GMT[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:13:11,261] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:13:11,262] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Via: 1.1 vegur[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:13:11,262] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:13:11,263] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "a[\r][\n]"
...
```

HTTPS:

```
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,301] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "GET /entries?title=Open%20Skills HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,302] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Accept: */*[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,303] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Postman-Token: a4c8fdcf-4957-46b1-8b35-589215ac89d6[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,305] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,306] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "eti-organizationid: org634bbfb6[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,306] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Content-Type: none[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,307] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Host: api.publicapis.org[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,309] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,310] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "User-Agent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,311] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,445] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,445] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,446] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Content-Length: 245[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,447] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,448] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Date: Tue, 02 Nov 2021 09:07:23 GMT[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,448] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "Server: Caddy[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,449] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "X-Rate-Limit-Duration: 1[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,450] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "X-Rate-Limit-Limit: 10.00[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,452] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "X-Rate-Limit-Request-Forwarded-For: 20.75.122.9[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,454] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "X-Rate-Limit-Request-Remote-Addr: 172.17.0.1:49674[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,454] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,454] DEBUG {wire} - HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "{"count":1,"entries":[{"API":"Open Skills","Description":"Job titles, skills and related jobs data","Auth":"","HTTPS":false,"Cors":"unknown","Link":"https://github.com/workforce-data-initiative/skills-api/wiki/API-Overview","Category":"Jobs"}]}[\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,478]  INFO {LogMediator} - {api:smp-serviceability-check-api} Finished.......... = Hello, Result = {"count":1,"entries":[{"API":"Open Skills","Description":"Job titles, skills and related jobs data","Auth":"","HTTPS":false,"Cors":"unknown","Link":"https://github.com/workforce-data-initiative/skills-api/wiki/API-Overview","Category":"Jobs"}]}

[2021-11-02 11:07:23,482] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,483] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 << "X-Rate-Limit-Request-Forwarded-For: 20.75.122.9[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,483] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 << "Server: Caddy[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,484] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 << "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,485] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 << "X-Rate-Limit-Duration: 1[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,486] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 << "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,487] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 << "X-Rate-Limit-Limit: 10.00[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,487] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 << "X-Rate-Limit-Request-Remote-Addr: 172.17.0.1:49674[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,488] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 << "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: [\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,488] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 << "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,489] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 << "Date: Tue, 02 Nov 2021 09:07:23 GMT[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,489] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,490] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 << "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,490] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 << "[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,491] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 << "f5[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,492] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 << "{"count":1,"entries":[{"API":"Open Skills","Description":"Job titles, skills and related jobs data","Auth":"","HTTPS":false,"Cors":"unknown","Link":"https://github.com/workforce-data-initiative/skills-api/wiki/API-Overview","Category":"Jobs"}]}[\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,493] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 << "[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,493] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 << "0[\r][\n]"
[2021-11-02 11:07:23,494] DEBUG {wire} - HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 << "[\r][\n]"
...
```

I guess there might be something wrong with the target endpoint even if it works with Postman..

Integration Studio 7.2.0
Micro Integrator 1.2.0

Comment: you can compare the MI outgoing request wire logs with postman request details(get the curl command in postman) and try to see whether there is any difference. Need to compare the all the headers and the payload

Comment: Hey Dil, thanks for your answer. I did all of that and at the end it was a simple json server on the client side with base configurations. It was experiencing problems when calls were coming from wso2 but it was fixed by updating their configuration. Can't tell you what exactly was updated as I wasn't a part of that configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved. The problem was that https://sub-domain.dns.net?qparam=999999999 was using a json server with base configurations. It was working properly with Postman but for some reason it wasn't working with wso2 calls from MI. The issue was resolved on the client side with the proper configuration of the json server.